# why geom_box plot bar does not appear in corect asending order for small numbers

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I am using geom_bar function to create a bar plot using following sample example.
The color bar of small values of Area such as 0.006 and 0.003 are does not appear in ascending order instead they shows higher values in graph.
Does someone know why its happening and how to fix it?
Thanks

```
library(ggplot2)
ID        <-  c(1,1,2,2,3,3)
Type      <-  c("Bc", "Ea", "Ea","Ra", "Lr","Ram")
Area      <- c(0.15,0.11, 0.0066,0.11,0.0037,0.088)
data.Table <- data.frame(ID ,Type,Area )
p         <- ggplot(dataTable)+ 
         geom_bar(aes(fill=Type, y=Area, x=ID), stat="identity")
print(p)
```

Comment: The order of your bars is determined by `ID`. As you have multiple bars per `ID` these get stacked by default, where the stack is ordered alphabetcially by `Type`. Maybe you could clarify how you would your bars to be ordered, simply by `Area` or .. should they be stacked or dodged or ..

Comment: I would like color bar to be organized by ID on X -axis and with multiple color box on Y axis based on Type. Similar output the sample code generate but the values should appear at correct location which is ascending values  ID 2,and 3. With current plot it looks  like a for ID 2 and 3 type Ea and Lr has larger area but its not correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reorder the stacked bars in ascending order by Area you could use `reorder(Type,-Area)`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ID        <-  c(1,1,2,2,3,3)
Type      <-  c("Bc", "Ea", "Ea","Ra", "Lr","Ram")
Area      <- c(0.15,0.11, 0.0066,0.11,0.0037,0.088)
data.Table <- data.frame(ID ,Type,Area )

p         <- ggplot(data.Table)+ 
  geom_bar(aes(fill=reorder(Type, -Area), y=Area, x=ID), stat="identity")
print(p)
```

[image]

**EDIT** If the y-axis should show the values of Area for each bar, i.e. the bars should not be stacked on top of each other, but addtionally the bars should not be dodged then the only option I could think of is to overlay the bars using `position="identity"` (or perhaps `position = position_dodge(width = .1)` which gives a mix of dodging and overlaying). In that case we have to order the dataset such that the observations with small Area are at the end (per ID) which could be achieved via `data.Table[order(ID, -Area),]`. Additionally, in that case we don't have to reorder Type:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ID        <-  c(1,1,2,2,3,3)
Type      <-  c("Bc", "Ea", "Ea","Ra", "Lr","Ram")
Area      <- c(0.15,0.11, 0.0066,0.11,0.0037,0.088)
data.Table <- data.frame(ID ,Type,Area )

data.Table01<- data.Table[order(ID, -Area),]
ggplot(data.Table01) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill=Type, y=Area, x=ID), stat="identity", position = "identity")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Stefan. The values of ID 1 are no longer same ?

Comment: @uday You are welcome. I had a look at the data. The values are the same. Only the colors for the `Type`s and the order in the legend have changed.

Comment: yes you are correct. is there any way we could limit plot ID one to two colours with Bc =0.15?

Comment: Almost everything is possible. (; But I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean by "limit plot ID one to two colours with Bc =0.15" and how you would like the bars to be colored. At the moment the fill color is determined by Type. So we could easily set different colors for the Types. Maybe you could try to clarify what you have in mind.

Comment: What I would like to do is Y axis and color bar box should show the true value range of area e.g. ID 2: Ea appears at the bottom (lower value) and Ra appears at top end ( higher value). In ID 1 Ea  is 0.11 so its at the bottom and Bc should be at higher than Ea but at 0.15 location. Currently Bc appears 0.15 above Ea. I hope I explain it clearly.

Comment: Hi @uday. I just made an edit to show you another option for your chart. Instead of stacking I use dodging. This way the y-axis reflects the value of Area, where the bars for each ID are orderd in ascending order of Area. BTW: Don't be confused by the change in colors and legend order.

Comment: Hello @ Stefan. The data is here is very small sample. If I use the "dodge" position then it will be super long bar plot to interpret. I wanted to plot  "stack" position with different color  stacked in single bar for a individual ID. I tried  dataTable01<- dataTable[order(ID ,Area),] but still the Bc orange color shows > 0.20 value on Y axis.

Comment: Hi @uday. I just added another option. If you don't want the bars to be stacked, but dodging is also not an option then perhaps you want the bars to be overlayed. Yet another option would be to make use of e.g. `position = position_dodge(width = .1)` which gives a mix of dodgeing and overlaying.

Comment: thanks for your prompt replies. Actually your edited solution works perfectly ! I just rerun you edited answer.